# How to get one line above the enabled crontab entry

Tags: grep, cron, string, search

I have the below crontab entries

```
$ crontab -l
#Cron to auto restart app1
#Ansible: test1
#*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/va_action.yml


#Cron to auto restart app7

#Ansible: test7
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out


#Cron to restart Apache services on automation server

#Ansible: test3
0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Below are the enabled cron entries:

```
crontab -l | grep  -v '#' | tr -d '\n'

*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out
0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

I understand `grep -B1` will give me one line above the grep string.

As you can see the comment above thee enabled cron entries are

```
#Ansible: test1
#Ansible: test7
```

Thus i wish to list test1 & test7 as my desired output using `| awk '{print $2}'`

Desired output:

```
test1
test7
```

Comment: It looks like you already have the commands to do what you want (`grep` and `awk`). It's not as efficient as it might be, but it would work. What's the issue you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do all the work of processing the output of `crontab -l`.

The idea is to ignore blank lines, capture the text associated with comment lines, and print out the captured text when you get other lines. You mention that you want only the second field, so we will only save that.

```
crontab -l | awk '/^$/ { next ; }
                  /^#/ { text=$2 ; }
                  /^[^#]/ { print text; }'
```

There are multiple ways to write this, but I think this is about as clear as it gets. There are 3 patterns to select blank lines, lines starting with `#` and lines which don't. Note however that this does depend on you putting a comment for every entry in the crontab that is active